# Java - calculating String length

Tags: java, string, char, java-native-interface

While initializing array, Java ask length for that array. Otherwise we get compile-time error.

```
char[] b = new char[3];
```

Here **3** is the length of that array **b**.we can get it from **b.length**

When we see constructor of String class

```
 public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

Where that **original** parameter in String constructor came? How that get its length?

In String length method

```
    public int length() {
    return value.length;
}
```

**MyQuestion #1**

How can we get the length without initialize array(Since no array initialization inside constructor)?

**MyQuestion #2**

```
String s = new String("MyString");
```

In the above line I am creating instance for `String` class, when I checked the constructor for the `String` class I come across the following code for the constructor

```
 public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

My doubt is inside the constructor how they are having String class itself as a parameter? From where it is loading?

Comment: This is unclear; are you asking what `new String("MyString")` does?  What does that have to do with length?

Comment: It's [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) as compared to `value.length`. The literal `"MyString"` is also a `String`, and has a fixed length (because Java `String` is immutable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statement constructs a `String` instance `s` out of a "String literal" in this case `"MyString"`

```
String s = new String("MyString");
```

It is equivalent and less preferable to

```
String s = "MyString";
```

According to the official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html)

1. A string literal is a reference to an instance of class String (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
2. A string literal always refers to the same instance of class String (interning)

Regarding specifically the length of `"MyString"`, the compiler would count the number of chars in the literal when parsing the source code and initialize the `char[]` inside that string with the appropriate length. Then it would create a new `String s` with the same length

As a side note, you can (for similar reasons) create an array without specifying the length yourself. The compiler will count the number of elements and set the length accordingly E.g.

```
char[] b = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Comment: If compiler counts the char, then how it will works when I initialize it while run time? I could not get it.

Comment: You are creating a `String` by passing another `String` that has a length field. If you provide a string literal at compile time, the compiler will create a `String` object and pass it to the copy constructor

Comment: My question is how does that String (in constructor parameter) has length?

Comment: It's an object of class `String` and that class has a `length` field. The compiler will create a object of class `String` out of a string literal.

Answer (score -2):

Java allows to give parameter of same class object in which you are writing constructor or other methods.

```
 public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

String class gets length from hash, as hash has a unique code which tells how many chracters are there.